# Qual é a finalidade da coluna do tipo JSON em MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, json

Percebi que o Mysql lançou uma nova funcionalidade, que é a coluna poder ter o tipo `JSON` (que inclusive pode ser salvo em binário, segundo eu estava lendo).

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html):

> As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type that enables efficient access to data in JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) documents.

Que traduzindo, é:

> A partir do `MySQL 5.7.8`, MySQL suporta nativamente o tipo de dados `JSON` que permite o acesso eficiente aos dados em `JSON` (JavaScript Object Notation).

- Com essa implementação, quais são as vantagens adquiridas? Existe alguma diferença de performance ou facilidade recuperação desses valores?
- Usar simplesmente um campo do tipo `TEXT` para salvar meu `JSON` não era o suficiente?

Comment: acho que essa tag não é referente a do banco.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

São muitas as vantagens do campo `JSON` em relação ao `TEXT`:

- **Validação** – Os dados são validados automaticamente. Se o JSON for inválido, o registro não será inserido e a operação vai produzir um erro
- **Acesso eficiente** – O formato de armazenamento é otimizado. Os documentos JSON salvos nas colunas do tipo `JSON` são na verdade convertidos num formato interno que permite leitura rápida aos elementos do documento. Quando o servidor precisar ler um valor JSON armazenado nesse formato binário, o valor não precisa ser convertido a partir de uma representação em texto.
- **Desempenho** – É possível melhorar o desempenho da query criando índices dentro das colunas do JSON. Isso é possível através dos [índices secundários em colunas virtuais](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes-virtual-columns.html).
- **Conveniência** – É bem mais fácil recuperar valores nas queries através da função [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) ou com a nova sintaxe `coluna->caminho`:

  `SELECT nome, conta->"$.saldo" FROM clientes WHERE conta->"$.atrasada" = true;`

Portanto, agora é muito mais fácil manipular os dados e armazenar esses valores complexos numa coluna. Pode-se dizer que o MySQL suporta uma estrutura de dados não relacional (NoSQL) dentro de uma estrutura relacional. Incrível!

No entanto, como diz o [artigo MySQL 5.7 brings sexy back with JSON](https://www.symfony.fi/entry/mysql-5-7-8-brings-sexy-back-with-json), note que:

> Bancos de dados especializados em NoSQL (bancos orientados a documentos, bancos de chave-valor e bancos baseados em grafos) continuam sendo opções melhores para seus casos de uso específicos, mas a adição deste tipo de dado pode permitir que você reduza a complexidade da sua stack de tecnologia.