# Qual a melhor maneira para armazenar um array em um único campo no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Geralmente é utilizado `implode/explode` ou `serialize/unserialize` para armazenar múltiplas informações de um determinado item no banco de dados. Utilizando PDO, qual seria a melhor e se existe outra maneira para armazenar um array em um único campo do banco de dados?

Comment: Geralmente não é recomendado criar colunas multivaloradas :P se realmente precisar e estiver usando a versão 5.7 do MySQL pode criar uma coluna do tipo json.

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual é a finalidade da coluna do tipo JSON em MYSQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153294/91)

Comment: @rray, em resumo, o certo é criar um campo do tipo JSON no banco? Sendo assim, como faria pra armazenar tais dados utilizando PDO? Utilizo `PDO::PARAM_STR`?

Comment: O ideal é normalizar suas tabelas, por exemplo ia precisar uma tabela para noticias outra para categorias e uma associativa para amarrar **uma noticia a várias categorias**. Se não for possível crie uma coluna do tipo json, para o PDO pode passar como string (`PDO::PARAM_STR`) mesmo.